# Can't upload to nano esp32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, uploading, port-mapping

Recently bought a nano esp32 to play around with the small size and wifi module. However I'm plagued by the `No DFU capable USB device available` message. [image: exist status 74 err]

My efforts and deductions:

- I can connect to my Uno boards just fine.
- I have reset the bootloader [see here](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/9810414060188-Reset-the-Arduino-bootloader-on-the-Nano-ESP32) successfully, however it opens a new COM port that after reset is gone
- Restarted the IDE, Redownloaded the IDE, made sure it's up to date
- Tried numerous cabling (eg. cables for ssd's, charging, etc) nothing seems to work except on that one port  that is opened upon the bootloader reset.
- The arduino IDE will identify a port (in my case COM 9) and recognize it, however returns this error
- I have done the double tap on the `RST` button
- I have made sure that the esp32 is selected and the dependencies for it is installed
- I am using just a simple web server sketch
- As far as I can tell theres the port that its being picked up as and the actual port it should be on, however the IDE rarely detects it and if it does its only for a moment and is incredibly inconsistent

I am new to this IoT world so there's most likely an oversight on my part but please try to be kind and not stack overflow me into oblivion :D

I should note that I am just trying to upload anything to the nano esp32without this error occurring

```
Sketch uses 721325 bytes (22%) of program storage space. Maximum is 3145728 bytes.
Global variables use 56580 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 271100 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
dfu-util 0.11-arduino4

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2021 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to http://sourceforge.net/p/dfu-util/tickets/

Cannot open DFU device 2341:0070 found on devnum 20 (LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
No DFU capable USB device available
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 74
```